# How do I create a Modal UITypeEditor for a string property?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a property which is stored as a string and is to be edited via a PropertyGrid  It is kept as a set of comma separated values e.g ABC, DEF, GHI.  My users could edit the string directly but the values come from a closed set of values.  So it is easier and safer for them to pick from a list.

I have written a simple custom UITypeEditor based on the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016239/how-to-create-custom-propertygrid-editor-item-which-opens-a-form)

I also reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538293/property-set-isnt-being-triggered-with-a-uitypeeditor-implemented) but I did not really understand it might relate to my problem. 8-(

I set up a simple form that allows the user to pick from a list and the picked values are added to value to be returned.  My problem is that the value is not being returned.  I wondered if this is something to do with the immutability of strings.  However it is probably something simple and stupid that I am doing.

Here is my code for the type editor based on Marc's answer:

```
   public class AirlineCodesEditor : UITypeEditor
    {

        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }

        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            var svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
            var codes = value as string;

            if (svc != null && codes != null)
            {
                using (var form = new AirlineCodesEditorGUI())
                {
                    form.Value = codes;
                    if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        codes = form.Value; // update object
                    }
                }
            }

            return value; // can also replace the wrapper object here
        }

    }
```

The form is trivial for my test I just edited the textbox with some new values:

```
   public partial class AirlineCodesEditorGUI : Form
    {


        public AirlineCodesEditorGUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        public string Value {
            get
            {
                return airlineCodes.Text;
            }

            set
            {
                airlineCodes.Text = value;
            } 
        }

        private void OnCloseButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Perhaps someone would put me out of my misery.

Comment: `return value;` should be `return codes;`

Comment: Thanks Hans - that worked.  The answer below also works - it seems that provided they are both either codes or value then it works, if they are different it doesn't.

Comment: You just plain forgot to return the value returned by the modal form :)

Comment: @Hans.  Yes - I knew it would be something stupid on my part :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to return the value from the form, like this:

```
 if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     value = form.Value;
 }
```